# VBA excel protecting sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I created a spreadsheet where on Work Book Open Event i create a sheet called "Hello". This works perfectly fine. The problem arises when I Protect the structure of the WORKBOOK with password. Now when i open my workbook and try to add the sheet to it, the application gives me an error on this line of code where I'm adding the sheet. All my code below

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim isHELLOexist As Boolean
 isHELLOexist = False
 For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
     If Worksheets(i).Name = "HELLO" Then
         isHELLOexist = True
     End If
 Next i

 If isHELLOexist = False Then
     Set ws = Sheets.Add '''here's where i get an error with ADDING sheet
     ws.Name = "HELLO"
 End If
 End Sub
```

Now this code works perfectly fine as long as STRUCTURE of workbook is not protected with password. What should i do here to get this to work?

ERROR states:

> METHOD ADD OF OBJECT SHEETS FAILED ERROR 1004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out....I first need to unprotect the workbook, add the sheet and protect it again like this...

```
thisworkbook.unprotect("password")
If isHELLOexist = False Then
     Set ws = Sheets.Add '''here's where i get an error with ADDING sheet
     ws.Name = "HELLO"
End If
thisworkbook.protect("password"),true,true
```